# KineticJS: Play tween after finish other tween

Tags: javascript, animation, kineticjs

I just need animate something, i need create few tween for feew difrent object, example bubbles. So i just want animate bubble per bubble, i mean start animate bubble number two when animation bubble numer one was end. I write somethink like that:

```
var tweens = [];
      for(var i =0; i < bubbleTab.length; i++)
      {
        var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
          node: bubbleTab[i], 
          x: invisibleBubbles[i].getX(),
          y: invisibleBubbles[i].getY(),
          easing: Kinetic.Easings.BounceEaseOut,
          onFinish: function(){
          tweens[i+1].play();
          },
          duration: 2
        });

        tweens.push(tween);
      }
```

or i just replace `onFinish: function()` to `playNextTween(i)` and write method

```
function playNextTween(i)
      {

        tweens[i].play();

      }
```

But still isn't working. I don't know what i can do. I try animate tween in loop but in loop all tween execute in the same time.

Any ideas? I know about GSAP and his TweenTimeline but with KineticJS no one ease from GSAP working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using

`tweens[i+1].play();`

Use a variable counter to iterate through your tween array. For example:

```
    var rects = layer.get('Rect');
    var rectCount = rects.length;

    var tweens = [];
    var tweenCounter = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < rectCount; i++) {
        var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
            node: rects[i],
            duration: 1,
            y: 150,
            onFinish: function() {
                if (tweenCounter !== rectCount) { //Prevent an undefined tween from being played at the end
                    tweens[tweenCounter].play();
                    tweenCounter++;
                }
            }
        });
        tweens.push(tween);
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/sWDQa/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to @projeqht i know how do this with KineticJS but i working on it, and i have better solution with GASP. Cause with GASP i can overlap animation and much more ;) so here is the code:

```
//Dodawanie animacje kolejnego bombla do timeline
        function addAnim(i){
            tl.to(bubbleTab[i], 0.5, {kinetic:{scaleX:1, scaleY:1}}, "-=0.45");//-0.45 mean overlap
        }

//Dodawanie animacji do timeline
        for(var i = 0; i < bubbleTab.length; i++)
        {
            layer.add(bubbleTab[i])
            addAnim(i);
        }

tl.play()
```

It's simple doesn't it? But you must remeber to add kineticJS plugin :D i fo